# Understanding the fastaread function in matlab

Tags: matlab

I searched [the documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/bioinfo/ref/fastaread.html) about the fastaread function, but I'm still kind of confused about the Sequence part.

So, suppose my file is stored in the `file_path` location, and `fastaread(file_path)` will return the data obtained.

`fastaread` returns two columns, one is with title header and the other one is with title sequence. Then, `fastaread(file_path).sequence` will return the sequence column? Does that mean that `fastaread(file_path).sequence` is a column vector?

Comment: After digging a bit, I found out that the fastaread function returns a struct array with two fields, header and sequence. So, is struct array the same as a normal array?

Comment: Please have a look at my answer below, a "normal" array, i.e. numeric array, is not the same as a structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it's a row vector containing characters.

Example with data provided with Matlab:

```
p53nt = fastaread('p53nt.txt')
```

gives a structure with 2 fields: `Header` and `Sequence`.

`p53nt.Header` gives info about the actual sequence:

```
p53nt.Header

ans =

gi|8400737|ref|NM_000546.2| Homo sapiens tumor protein p53 (Li-Fraumeni syndrome) (TP53), mRNA
```

while `p53nt.Sequence` gives a character array of size `1xN`:

```
S = p53nt.Sequence

S =

ACTTGTCATGGCGACTGTCCAGC... And so on
```

Typing `whos S` gives this:

```
Name      Size              Bytes  Class    Attributes

  S         1x2629             5258  char
```

So if you want a column vector for some reason, use the colon operator:

```
S = S(:);
```

Hope its a bit clearer now!

Comment: You're welcome. If my answer helped you please consider accepting it (green checkmark beside it). Thanks and good luck!

Comment: In the data file, the .Sequence is the single letter-code representation of a nucleotide sequence. So, the size of S is the 1X2629 means the total  number of nucleotides is 2629, right ?

Comment: Yes that's what I understand

Comment: char (fastaread(file_path).Sequence) is the same as fastaread(file_path).Sequence, since the function char(A) transfer an array A into an array of characters. Right ?